# Delete Lines : after pattern1 and between pattern2 and pattern3 using awk/sed/perl

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I need to delete lines from a file which are **after pattern1** and **between pattern 2 and pattern3**, as below:

```
aaaaaaaa 
bbbbbbbb
pattern1   <-----After this line
cdededed
ddededed
pattern2
fefefefe   <-----Delete this line
efefefef   <-----Delete this line
pattern3
adsffdsd
huaserew
```

Please can you suggest how this can be done using awk or sed or in perl.

Comment: If **pattern1** comes after **pattern2** should the deletion occur?

Answer (score 5):

```
sed '/pattern1/,${ /pattern2/,/pattern3/{/pattern2/b; /pattern3/b; d;} };' file
```

Formatted:

```
/pattern1/,$ {
    /pattern2/,/pattern3/ {
        /pattern2/b;
        /pattern3/b; 
        d;
    } 
}
```

Explained:

- `/pattern1/,$` is the range of lines after `pattern1` to the end of the file
- `/pattern2/,/pattern3/` is the range of lines between `pattern2` and `pattern3`
- `/pattern2/b;` and `/pattern3/b;` skips the `pattern2` and `pattern3` lines which are otherwise included in the range (see [the sed faq](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.24))
- `d` deletes the other lines in the range

**Update**

From the comments, the inner block can be rewritten:

```
//!d
```

where:

- `//` (an empty pattern) matches the last-used regex (which in this case is both `pattern2` and `pattern3`
- `!` inverts the next command so that it applies to everything *except* lines matching the pattern
- `d` deletes these lines

So the complete, rewritten pattern is:

```
/pattern1/,$ {
    /pattern2/,/pattern3/ {
        //!d
    } 
}
```

Comment: I agree; it's a limitation of sed. There's not really a better way to do this (in sed). awk and perl surely have more elegant solutions.

Comment: @glennjackman: You don't need to repeat the pattern: `sed '/pattern1/,${ /pattern2/,/pattern3/{//b; d;} };'`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson `//b;d` could be replaced by `//!d`

Comment: @potong, DennisWilliamson; I am glad to be proven wrong about there not being more elegant solutions; I've integrated your suggestions into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

use awk like a state machine:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {print_line = 1}
    /pattern1/ {consider = 1}
    consider && /pattern2/ {print_line = 0; print}
    consider && /pattern3/ {print_line = 1}
    print_line {print}
' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a quick solution on the command line using perl, this is an ideal case for the [`flip-flop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator. Now, there are two ways which this question can be interpreted in edge cases -- both of these will function the same so long as `pattern1` comes before `pattern2`:

1. If **pattern1** comes after **pattern2** but before **pattern3** delete everything in between **pattern1** and **pattern3**
2. or, If **pattern1** comes after **pattern2** but before **pattern3** do nothing *unless* you see another **pattern1**.

Before we start, take note of the perl arguement `-p`

```
-n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
-p                assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
```

Now, To the first, I give you..

```
perl -pe'$x ||= /7/; $_= "" if /5/ .. /8/ and $x' <(seq 1 10)
1
2
3
4
5
6
9
10
```

`$x ||= /7/`: This sets `$x` to the return value of `/7/` when `$x` is `false`. `/7/` will return `true` when it matches. This means `$x` gets set to true, on the first match and the nature of `||=` is never to set the variable when it is already true.

Then it sets `$_ = ''` if the range is between `/5/` and `/8/` and it has already set `$x` to true. Remember the way short-circuiting works: `a && b` means run `b` only if `a` evaluates to `true`. In this case, the mere fact of evaling `a` will set the state of the flip-flop operator -- that's what we want; yet, we only want the `$_ = ''` to occur if it's already seen `7`.

Now, to the second interpretation of the quesiton just switch the order...

```
perl -pe'$x ||= /7/; $_= "" if $x and /5/ .. /8/' <(seq 1 10)
```

This will print the full range. Perl won't start looking for `/5/` until after it finds `/7/`. In our sequential range that won't happen.

BTW, to really put some of these answers to shame, many of the spaces are not required...

```
perl -pe'$x||=/2/;$_=""if$x&&/5/../8/' # secksey
```

Comment: I don't interpret the question in either way. The question clearly indicates that pattern1 comes *before* pattern2.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson **both** of them handle that case fine.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I still don't see that `pattern1` coming before `pattern2` as being evident in the question, the example has that but it may be happenstance. **I need to delete lines from a file which are after pattern1 and between pattern 2 and pattern3** why can't `pattern1` be between `pattern2` and `pattern3`? setting the deletion range from `pattern1` to `pattern3`

Comment: @tchrist fear not, I have [plenty of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/124486/evan-carroll?tab=answers) you can upvote!

Comment: The flip flop operator is appealing, but this solution also deletes `pattern2` and `pattern3`, which are not to be deleted.  Also, this solution actually loses to the sed in code golf: `sed '/3/,${/5/,/8/{//!d}}` is only 21 chars, vs 28.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the Rosetta Stone:

```
perl -ne '++$saw_pattern1 if /pattern1/;
          $inside = ($saw_pattern1 && /pattern2/) .. /pattern3/;
          print unless $inside && ($inside > 1 && $inside !~ /E0$/)' \
  input
```

The code takes advantage of Perl’s [`..` range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

> In scalar context, `..` returns a boolean value. The operator is bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma) operator of *sed*, *awk*, and various editors. Each `..` operator maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false. Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, *AFTER* which the range operator becomes false again. It doesn’t become false till the next time the range operator is evaluated …
>
> The right operand is not evaluated while the operator is in the false state, and the left operand is not evaluated while the operator is in the true state. The precedence is a little lower than `||` and `&&`. The value returned is either the empty string for false, or a sequence number (beginning with 1) for true. The sequence number is reset for each range encountered. The final sequence number in a range has the string `E0` appended to it, which doesn't affect its numeric value, but gives you something to search for if you want to exclude the endpoint. You can exclude the beginning point by waiting for the sequence number to be greater than 1.

Comment: I updated this with a [much more concise perl answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10961632/124486).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/pattern1/,$!b;/pattern2/,/pattern3/!b;//!d' file
```